# ROS Groovy setup suggestions with Virtualbox

Tags: ros, virtualbox

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to ROS and I have Ubuntu 12.04 setup in a virtual box on my macbook pro retina display. I have 2 processors set aside along with 2GB RAM and 128MB video. I have 20GB disk with 1GB swap. And I have installed Guest Additions.

Anyways, I was just wondering if there were any other suggestions.

Thanks

Chet

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/130821/ros-groovy-setup-suggestions-with-virtualbox/) by [chet](https://answers.ros.org/users/12131/chet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One thing I have done in the past is install ROS on OS X and the guest Ubuntu and let them talk locally. This way you can install packages that only work only on Ubuntu in the virtual machine, but run ressource intesive stuff on the Mac (e.g. rviz).

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chet](https://answers.ros.org/users/12131/chet/) on 2014-02-26**:
thats cool. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've found that the visualisation performance (Gazebo and RViz) is quite poor when running ROS in Virtualbox on my Mac. I have also had issues with sensors working correctly in a virtual machine.

I eventually made an Ubuntu partition specifically for ROS, and that has worked out very well. If you're happy with the more permanent nature of that approach, I would strongly recommend it.

---

Originally posted by [mardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/10151/mardo/) with karma: 126 on 2014-02-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chet](https://answers.ros.org/users/12131/chet/) on 2014-02-26**:
that makes sense. It just seems that pub -r shouldn't be so intensive...